# bind many data frames adding a column with their id

Tags: r, dataframe

I have many data frames named repeatably:

```
df.1 <- data.frame("x"=c(1,2), "y"=2)
df.2 <- data.frame("x"=c(2,4), "y"=4)
df.3 <- data.frame("x"=2, "y"=c(4,5))
```

All data frames have the same number of rows and columns.
I want to bind them, adding a column with the id of the data frame. The id would be the name of the source data frame.

I know I could do this manually:

```
rbind(data.frame(id = "df.1", df.1),
      data.frame(id = "df.2", df.2),
      data.frame(id = "df.3", df.3))
```

But there's a lot of them and their number will change in the future.

I tried writing for loops but they didn't work. I suppose that's because I'm basing them on a list of strings containing data frames' names rather than a list of data frames themselves.

```
df_names <- ls(pattern = "df.\\d+")

for (i in df_names) {
  i$id <- i
  i
}
```

...but I also haven't found any automated way of creating a list of data frames with repeatable names. And even if I do, I'm not that sure the for-loop above would work :)

Comment: Try  `eval(parse(text="df.1"))` for example

Comment: not really sure where...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `parse` and `eval` to get the data frames from `df_names`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df_names, function(x){data.frame(id=x, eval(parse(text=x)))}))


    id x y
1 df.1 1 2
2 df.1 2 2
3 df.2 2 4
4 df.2 4 4
5 df.3 2 4
6 df.3 2 5
```

Comment: If data frames have more than one row it adds ids as a sequence. I've modified the example to account for that. So you get 2 first rows coming from df.1, but the id column will have values "df.1" in row 1 and "df.2" in row 2.

Comment: It works for me, for example with `df.1 <- data.frame("x"=c(1,2), "y"=c(2,3))`.

Comment: you could use `get` instead of `eval(parse())`: `do.call(rbind, lapply(df_names, function(x){data.frame(id=x, get(x))}))`.

Comment: Great! Now I can even understand what it all means (and works identically) :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There is also `combine` from the "gdata" package:

```
library(gdata)
combine(df.1, df.2, df.3)
#   x y source
# 1 1 2   df.1
# 2 2 2   df.1
# 3 2 4   df.2
# 4 4 4   df.2
# 5 2 4   df.3
# 6 2 5   df.3
```

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware of this function.

Comment: That's what I love and hate R for - there're solutions simple enough out there but not always easy to find and at the cost of loading another package.... I'll stay with the first approach as understanding it teaches me more flexibility for future usage.

Comment: @KubaKrukar, I think the `get` solution posted by GSee and the `AppendMe` function I proposed in the linked duplicate question (which also uses `get`) seem to be more suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `mget`:

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, mget(df_names))
dat$id <- sub("\\.\\d+$", "", rownames(dat))

#        x y   id
# df.1.1 1 2 df.1
# df.1.2 2 2 df.1
# df.2.1 2 4 df.2
# df.2.2 4 4 df.2
# df.3.1 2 4 df.3
# df.3.2 2 5 df.3
```